# New duplicate record created in WPF c# instead of update the record

Tags: c#, wpf, icommand

I have a record that I need to update.  I pass the object like so

```
<Button x:Uid="EditButton" x:Name="EditButton" Width="20px" Height="20px" 
VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,0,0,2" 
Command="{Binding Path=PatientViewModel.ProviderContacts.EditProvider}" 
 Content="Edit" CommandParameter="{Binding   
  Path=PatientViewModel.ProviderContacts.ReferringProvider}" />
```

This pulls up the provider dialog box (with other code) and allows me to make changes with the user being updated in the fields.  When I try to edit the command it just creates a new duplicate provider.

Here is my edit code

```
<Button x:Uid="Button_EditCommand" Margin="0,0,2,0" Command="{Binding Path=EditCommand}" Style="{StaticResource btnCustom}" MinWidth="75">Edit</Button>


public ICommand EditCommand { get; private set; }

EditCommand = new RelayCommand(o => Save(), o => CanSave);
```

Save Method

```
 private void Save()
  {
     IsBusy = true;
     providerSaver.BeginInvoke(Provider, OnSaveEnd, null);
  }

public bool CanSave
  {
     get { return properties.Get(() => CanSave); }
     private set { properties.Set(() => CanSave, value); }
  }
```

Comment: does the code in Save method check and update if there are changes to the existing object ?

Comment: updated with the save mthod

Comment: Look into the providerSaver to ensure that the SAVE is not creating another row (record).

Comment: Looks like its creating a new provider by inserting it into sql

Comment: I guess you figured it out.